# Обрезка видео перед фильтром размытия boxblur

Tags: ffmpeg

Вот [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30789367/ffmpeg-how-to-convert-vertical-video-with-black-sides-to-video-169-with-blur/30832903) нашел как сделать размытый фон у вертикального видео:

```
ffmpeg -i <input_file> -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=ih*16/9:-1,boxblur=luma_radius=min(h\,w)/20:luma_power=1:chroma_radius=min(cw\,ch)/20:chroma_power=1[bg];[bg][0:v]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2,crop=h=iw*9/16" <output_file>
```

Но не понятно как можно его обрезать до нужного размера до этого фильтра. Пытался вставит crop в начале перед scale=ih*16/9:-1, но все равно между видео и размытым фоном остаются черные полосы. Может кто сталкивался с этим.